# Applying Laplacian filter in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, filter

I got two errors as

> non-scalar operator

and

> Undefined function 'unit8'

Here is the code:

```
clc 
clear all 
close all 
image=double('img.tif');
filter=[0 -1 0 ; -1 5 -1 ; 0 -1 0];
[rows,cols] = size(image);
outputimage = zeros(rows,cols);
for row = 2:rows-1
    for col = 2:col-1 
        outputimage (row,col)= sum (sum(image(row-1: row+1: col-1: col+1: filter ))); 
    end
end 
%figure,imshow (unit8(image)),title ('Originalimage')
outputimage =unit8(outputimage);
figure,imshow (outputimage, title('Enchanceimage'))
```

Comment: You have several problems. Firstly, for `unit8` you probably mean `uint8`, secondly, `image=double('img.tif');` does not load the image, you probably want `imread`. Try reading the documentation first :)

Answer (score 2):

**Solution One**

there is a way to compute your masking without for loops.
here is the code:

```
clc 
clear all 
close all 
image=imread('img.tif');
filter=[0 -1 0 ; -1 5 -1 ; 0 -1 0];
[rows,cols] = size(image);
outputimage = zeros(rows,cols);
filtered_3x3 = imfilter(image,filter,'replicate');
outputimage = im2uint8(filtered_3x3);
imshow(outputimage);
```

first you should read images with `imread` function and with `imfilter` you can apply your mask to your image. with `im2uint8` you can convert your image to uint8.

**Solution Two**

If you want to change your own code, some lines need to be changed. here is the code:

```
clc 
clear all 
close all 
image=imread('img.tif');
filter=[0 -1 0 ; -1 5 -1 ; 0 -1 0];
rows = size(image,1);
cols = size(image,2);
outputimage = zeros(rows,cols);

for row = 2:rows-1
    for col = 2:cols-1
        for i=1:3
        outputimage (row,col,i)= sum (sum(double(image(row-1: row+1, col-1: col+1 , i)) .* filter )); 
        end
    end
end 
image =uint8(image);
figure,imshow (outputimage)
```

first you should read the image with `imread`. `size(image)` will not give you the correct dimension, so assign them with

`rows = size(image,1); cols = size(image,2);` . moreover, it is `col = 2:cols-1` not `col = 2:col-1` . There was a syntax error in your loops. Check it. with `for i=1:3` you can apply your mask to each `RGB` matrix. At the end, it is `uint8` function not `unit8` one!

Comment: `im2uint8` will only convert an image to `uint8` if it **wasn't** `uint8` to begin with.  `image` will most likely be `uint8` so `im2uint8` has no effect.  This code also doesn't explain **why** the OP's code is wrong.  They misspelled the type as `unit8`.  The OP may also want to implement filtering by his/herself without relying on `imfilter`, which is a common exercise for anyone starting out in image processing.   You also don't need to define `outputimage` initially because the output of `im2uint8` will give you that already.... and `rows`, `cols` is no longer needed

Comment: Much better.  I wish I could give more than 1 upvote, but have one from me!